# Can I prove (in general) that two points in Euclidean geometry are equal?

Tags: algorithms, euclidean-geometry

If I construct points in Euclidean geometry (out of a given set of points, e.g. the four points of a unit square) by using circles and straight lines, can I always prove if two generated points are equal or not?

This boils down to something like this: If I add the square root operation to $\mathbb{Q}$, and look at a given number (which is the result of applying $+,-,\cdot, /, \sqrt{}$ finitely often to some natural numbers), can I always prove whether this number is equal to zero? In other words: Is there an algorithm that decides this?

Comment: .... If you just take $\sqrt{2}$, a finite application of those operations to $2$, the result is nonzero.... Why do you expect zero?

Comment: @rschwieb 1. To determine whether two numbers are equal is as difficult as to determine whether a number is zero (a=b <=> a-b=0).
2. The intersection of a circle and a line is a quadratic equation.

Comment: Well my point is this: *given number (which is the result of applying $+,-,\cdot, /, \sqrt{}$ finitely often to some natural numbers), can I always prove whether this number is equal to zero?*  My response was: $\sqrt{2}\neq 0$. So I guess some refinement in what you mean.

Comment: As for the line-circle thing, I went ahead and looked it up where I remember seeing it. Adopting the line-circle axiom (a line passing through the interior of a circle intersects the circle in two points) is equivalent to using an ordered field in which every positive element has a square root.  If by "Adding $\sqrt{}$" you mean that positive elements have square roots, then what you said is OK, but if you mean adding square roots for everything (that would be the quadratic closure), then *that* is a much stronger assumption.

Comment: Finally, let's look at the last question. The assumption is that you are carrying out a finite sequence of binary (and one unary) operations on natural numbers: under what conditions would you not be able to compute the end result? Why isn't it just arithmetic in the smallest ordered field whose (positive?) elements have square roots? I somewhat suspect that the title question is not as simple as the question you are asking in the last paragraph.

Comment: @rschwieb I am not quite sure that we talk about the same thing so let me give you an example. Let's say we have a number like $\sqrt{7}-\sqrt{5} - \sqrt{3}$. How do you prove whether this number is zero or not? Of course, if the number is _not_ zero, you can find appropriate higher/lower bounds for the different parts and get a proof through an inequality. But I don't know an algorithm that decides for each given number if it is zero or not.

Comment: Well, for this particular example would be solved as easily as $\sqrt{2}$ by contradiction and squaring both sides of the rearranged equation. But if you gave a more complex expression with weird nested radicals, perhaps it is less clear why it should be so. Maybe one can prove that when squaring both sides of an equation, the number of radicals decreases, or something like that. (This is not a precise argument, but I think the idea is right.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is a corollary of the [Tarski-Seidenberg theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%E2%80%93Seidenberg_theorem), which implies that it's algorithmically decidable which statements about Euclidean geometry are true (including statements about whether points are equal).

Comment: Do you whether an "understandable" algorithm exists for this? I mean one which you could actually grasp as a human or implement.